# What type of fitting connection is this?

Tags: fitting

This fitting for a pressure washer seems to be straight-threaded. The OD of the threaded portion is 16.18mm according to my caliper. Thread pitch is approximately 1.5mm. I need to convert this to NPT.

I first thought of ORB, but it doesn't appear to be the right type. Based on prior history with this vendor, there's a chance its a German DIN fitting. But I don't know enough about those to make a good ID.

[image: Fitting need identification]

Answer (score -1):

It appears to be a 1/2" threaded stop plug with an Allen wrench shaped hole in it . It also looks like the plumbing fitting itself may be 3/4" itself , with a 3/4" to 1/2" reducer in it.

The fitting, the way you hold it in the picture does give us a shot of the other side of it... Would need to see that too.

Comment: NPT does not use an o-ring seal. Also, the thread pitch and OD described don't match.

Comment: I know. That does not mean a person did not insert one. You must know this.